# Parameterize the solutions $x^2 + 5y^2 = z^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Parameterize the solutions in integers to $$x^2 + 5y^2 = z^2$$

To make it easier, consider only the solutions such that the GCD of x, y, and z is 1. Also
assume that x, y, and z are positive, and that x is odd. 
The analysis will probably still give two cases, but we can combine them into one by use of absolute values. Basically I have to prove that the analysis is correct.

Comment: Look at my solution for http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856758/solving-a23b2-c2/856801#856801 it is very similar to the problem you have posed.

Comment: @AnuragA Would you mind solving it again please. I would really like that.

Comment: I just modified that solution appropriately. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: @AnuragA And the part about the even in the previos problem has no impact on the answer, correct?

Comment: @AnuragA And what does the word parametrize mean to do?

Comment: No it doesn't because out of three variables one has to be even and two will be odd (for $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$). So without the loss of generality we can choose which one we would want to be even and then do the analysis accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to think about such problems is to convert this to 
$$\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^2+5\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^2=1,$$
and then think about rational points (both coordinates rational) on the curve
$$x^2+5y^2=1.$$
One obvious point is $(1,0)$. Let us consider a line that passes through this point $y=m(x-1)$ with rational slope $m$. Observe that all the points of intersection of this line and the curve (given above) will be rational. To find the intersection we solve
$$x^2+5m^2(x-1)^2=1.$$
This is equivalent to
$$x^2(5m^2+1)-10m^2x+(5m^2-1)=0.$$
Since one of the roots of this equation has to be $x=1$ (our trivial rational point) so the other root will be 
$$\alpha=\frac{5m^2-1}{5m^2+1}.$$
Thus we obtain the following point as the other point of intersection:
$$\left(\frac{5m^2-1}{5m^2+1}, \, \frac{-2m}{5m^2+1}\right).$$

So if we take $a=5m^2-1, b=-2m$ and $c=5m^2+1$ (with $m \in \mathbb{Z}$) then we can obtain integer solutions to the equation $a^2+5b^2=c^2$.

More generally, if we take $m=\frac{r}{s}$ (with $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $s \neq 0$) then we can have $a=5r^2-s^2, b=-2rs$ and $c=5r^2+s^2$ as the solutions.

Comment: But somehow $a=5m^2-1$, $b=-2m$, $c=5m^2+1$ misses the solution $a=2$, $b=1$, $c=3$.

Comment: I think what you're missing is solutions $a=(5r^2-s^2)/2$, $b=-rs$, $c=(5r^2+s^2)/2$ with $r\equiv s\bmod2$.

Comment: Any thoughts on my comments?

Comment: @GerryMyerson you are absolutely right about the missing solutions because I went with an extra assumption (though that was not part of the problem given by OP) that $b$ is even. Perhaps your last suggestion will take care of it. I need to think some more to be sure that I haven't missed other solutions. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $x^2+5y^2=z^2$ and $(x,y)=1$. Then there are $a,b$ so that $ax+by=1$, and therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
b^2x^2+5b^2y^2&=b^2z^2\tag1\\
b^2x^2+5(1-ax)^2&=b^2z^2\tag2\\
(10a-5a^2x-b^2x)x+(b^2z)z&=5\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: multiply $x^2+5y^2=z^2$ by $b^2$
$(2)$: apply $by=1-ax$
$(3)$: rearrange terms

$(3)$ implies that $(x,z)\mid5$. However, if $(x,z)=5$, then $25\mid z^2-x^2=5y^2$, which implies $5\mid y$, but that would mean $5\mid(x,y)$. Therefore, $(x,z)=1$.

Thus, $(z-x,z+x)\mid2(x,z)=2$.

If $(z-x,z+x)=1$, then
$$
\overbrace{\ (z\pm x)\ }^{5m^2}\overbrace{\ (z\mp x)\ }^{n^2}=5y^2
$$
$$
(x,y,z)=\tfrac12\left(\pm\left(5m^2-n^2\right),2mn,5m^2+n^2\right)
$$
where $(m,n)=1$, $m\equiv n\equiv1\pmod2$, and $n\not\equiv0\pmod5$.

If $(z-x,z+x)=2$, then
$$
\overbrace{\ (z\pm x)\ }^{10m^2}\overbrace{\ (z\mp x)\ }^{2n^2}=5y^2
$$
$$
(x,y,z)=\left(\pm\left(5m^2-n^2\right),2mn,5m^2+n^2\right)
$$
where $(m,n)=1$, $m+n\equiv1\pmod2$, and $n\not\equiv0\pmod5$.

---

Putting this all together, we have proven the following

**Theorem**

> All integer triplets, $(x,y,z)$, so that $x^2+5y^2=z^2$, where $(x,y)=1$, are given by:
>   $$
> \tfrac{[m+n\text{ is odd}]+1}2\left(\,\left|5m^2-n^2\right|,2mn,5m^2+n^2\,\right)
> $$
>   where $(5m,n)=1$ and $[\dots]$ are [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

---

**Examples**
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
(m,n)&(x,y,z)\\\hline
(1,1)&(2,1,3)\\
(1,2)&(1,4,9)\\
(2,1)&(19,4,21)\\
(1,3)&(2,3,7)\\
(3,1)&(22,3,23)\\
(1,4)&(11,8,21)\\
(2,3)&(11,12,29)\\
(3,2)&(41,12,49)\\
(4,1)&(79,8,81)\\
(5,1)&(62,5,63)\\
(1,6)&(31,12,41)\\
(3,4)&(29,24,61)\\
(4,3)&(71,24,89)\\
(5,2)&(121,20,129)\\
(6,1)&(179,12,181)
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Along with the solutions mentioned already, the other primitive solutions are given by
$$  x = 2 u^2 + 2uv - 2 v^2 \; , \; y = 2uv+v^2 \; , \; z = 2 u^2 + 2uv + 3 v^2   $$

This comes from Gauss composition; by fairly explicit formulas, the **square** of any number represented by $2 u^2 + 2uv + 3 v^2$ is then represented by $r^2 + 5 s^2 $

```
  z           x      y      z   recipe          u   v  
  1           1      0      1      A            1   0
  1           1      0      1     RAW 
  3          -2      1      3      B            0   1
  3          -2      1      3      B            0  -1
  3          -2     -1      3      B            1  -1
  3           2      1      3     RAW 
  7           2      3      7      B            1   1
  7           2     -3      7      B            2  -1
  7           2      3      7     RAW 
  9          -1      4      9      A            2   1
  9          -1     -4      9      A            2  -1
  9           1      4      9     RAW 
 21          11      8     21      A            4   1
 21          11     -8     21      A            4  -1
 21          11      8     21     RAW 
 21         -19      4     21      A            1   2
 21         -19     -4     21      A            1  -2
 21          19      4     21     RAW 
 23         -22      3     23      B            1  -3
 23         -22     -3     23      B            2  -3
 23          22      3     23     RAW 
 27          22      7     27      B            3   1
 27          22     -7     27      B            4  -1
 27          22      7     27     RAW 
 29         -11     12     29      A            3   2
 29         -11    -12     29      A            3  -2
 29          11     12     29     RAW 
 41          31     12     41      A            6   1
 41          31    -12     41      A            6  -1
 41          31     12     41     RAW 
 43          38      9     43      B            4   1
 43          38     -9     43      B            5  -1
 43          38      9     43     RAW 
 47           2     21     47      B            2   3
 47           2    -21     47      B            5  -3
 47           2     21     47     RAW 
 49         -41     12     49      A            2   3
 49         -41    -12     49      A            2  -3
 49          41     12     49     RAW 
 61         -29     24     61      A            4   3
 61         -29    -24     61      A            4  -3
 61          29     24     61     RAW 
 63          58     11     63      B            5   1
 63          58    -11     63      B            6  -1
 63          58     11     63     RAW 
 63         -62      5     63      B            2  -5
 63         -62     -5     63      B            3  -5
 63          62      5     63     RAW 
 67         -58     15     67      B            1  -5
 67         -58    -15     67      B            4  -5
 67          58     15     67     RAW 
 69          29     28     69      A            7   2
 69          29    -28     69      A            7  -2
 69          29     28     69     RAW 
 69          59     16     69      A            8   1
 69          59    -16     69      A            8  -1
 69          59     16     69     RAW 
 81         -79      8     81      A            1   4
 81         -79     -8     81      A            1  -4
 81          79      8     81     RAW 
 83          38     33     83      B            4   3
 83          38    -33     83      B            7  -3
 83          38     33     83     RAW 
 87         -38     35     87      B            1   5
 87         -38    -35     87      B            6  -5
 87          38     35     87     RAW 
 87          82     13     87      B            6   1
 87          82    -13     87      B            7  -1
 87          82     13     87     RAW 
 89         -71     24     89      A            3   4
 89         -71    -24     89      A            3  -4
 89          71     24     89     RAW 
101          61     36    101      A            9   2
101          61    -36    101      A            9  -2
101          61     36    101     RAW 
103         -22     45    103      B            2   5
  z           x      y      z   recipe          u   v
```